# JavaScript sum the number in the array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a following array `var total = [10, 0.25, 12.75, 1, 0];`

When I do:

```
 for (var i= 0; i< total.length; i++) {
      totalNo += parseInt(+(total[i]));
 }
```

The `totalNo` is always a full number. Looks like the `.XX` after dot value is skipped. How to make sure it is added properly?

Answer (score 4):

use `parseFloat()` instead of `parseInt()` to preserve decimal part

```
for (var i= 0; i< total.length; i++) {
      totalNo += parseFloat(total[i]);
}
```

*Note1: no need to write +(total[i])*
*Note2: as pointed out by Utkanos, if your array values contain only floating-point values, then parseFloat is not even necessary*

Comment: Or NewUser could use `+total[i]` instead of any parsing function. Let's remember that `parseFloat("10px") === 10`, and maybe that's not what we want.

Comment: +1 Good point about the [unary plus operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#.2B_(Unary_Plus)) - not necessary as `parseFloat` coerces to a Number.

Answer (score 4):

You shouldn't need to run any numeric coercion function (e.g. `parseInt`) - your array values are already numbers.

If an ECMA5 solution is acceptable, you can use `reduce()`:

```
var arr = [10, 0.25, 12.75, 1, 0];
alert(arr.reduce(function(curr_total, val) {
    return curr_total + val;
}, 0)); //24
```

Comment: A callback solution is way slower and could affect performances for large arrays.

Comment: @MaxArt - you're seriously voting me down for posting a *native* solution that does what he needs? You're sure that's a good candidate for vote-down?

Comment: you have my +1: in this specific question, the array contain only floating point values so there's no even need to use parseFloat. You correctly noted this

Comment: I still think it is, sorry. You could have a point if that could save some typing, but it's not. You could put a warning about it, and I'll remove the downvote together with the comments.

Comment: @MaxArt: bull****. http://jsperf.com/reduce-vs-native-loop. Performs 80% faster for reduce on chrome. Even if it was even or slower, I'd still prefer those methods for elegancy and convinients.

Comment: The code will be running mostly on IE8 - so ECMA5 is out of the question. But, very nice alternative.  Thanks!

Comment: @spaceman12: I don't see the fail sorry. The original statement was "its way slower", the "slower" part implies a comparison vs. the one other answer to this question, so I'm curios who is failing here. I never stated that a native loop is not faster in general.

Comment: @jAndy It is indeed an epic fail because doing _the same thing_ with a callback is, as I said, way slower than doing it with a classic loop. Your jsPerf example was flawed since it used `parseFloat` in each iteration, which is a rather slow function call. Thanks spaceman12 for pointing it out. If you want to take advantage of the fact that all the items of the array are numbers, then let's play on a fair ground.

Comment: @MaxArt: I guess my previous comment should be very clear about that, but I of course can repeat it just for you, but I'm actually too lazy for that. Go read again.

Comment: @jAndy No need, I understood perfectly. On the other hand, it's clear that you didn't understand that I was speaking generally, ("_A_ callback solution" instead of "_This_ callback solution") and not comparing two of these answers.

Answer (score 0):

You dont need either parseInt or parseFloat here. If speed is concerned and for large arrays, used the native loop, it is much faster! however care be be taken as how you code it -

```
var total = [10, 0.25, 12.75, 1, 0],totalNo=0;
var len=total.length;
for(var i= 0; i<len; i++) 
{
    totalNo = totalNo+total[i];
}
```

Always note that totalNo+=total[i] is slower than totalNo+total[i]

Comment: you can even improve that using a *reverse while loop* instead.